# PeriodFormmater in joda time

Tags: jodatime, period, periodformatter

Is it possible that a duration is formatted like following.

1. 8 hours will be considered as a day.
2. 5 days considered as a week

so 28800*1000 seconds duration will give output as 1d on periodformatting

Answer (score 1):

I’m afraid that it can’t be reduced to a question of formatting. You will have to do some math yourself.

```
    Period p = Period.hours(61);
    
    int days = p.toStandardHours().getHours() / HOURS_PER_DAY;
    Period remaining = p.minusHours(days * HOURS_PER_DAY);
    int weeks = days / DAYS_PER_WEEK;
    days -= weeks * DAYS_PER_WEEK;
    
    System.out.println("" + weeks + " weeks " + days + " days " + remaining);
```

Output:

> 1 weeks 2 days PT5H

As you may have guessed I am assuming these constants:

```
private static final int HOURS_PER_DAY = 8;
private static final int DAYS_PER_WEEK = 5;
```

I considered converting back to a new `Period` so that one might apply a `PeriodFormatter`, but I really don’t think it’s a good idea. A `Period` is meant for a period of physical time, not work time or the like.